# Need help vertically centering two elements

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I need to vertically center two elements (a div and a label). I've searched high and low and tried using various fixes (relative/absolute positioning, display:table, etc.) but I still can't get this to work how I need it to.

The kicker is that the image in the label is not a fixed height. The maximum will be 200x200, but it could be smaller than that. The size of the input button is roughly 16x16.

I can make some slight changes to the structure of the HTML but as it's not my code I can't do much with it. Thanks!

Here's the stripped down version of the code:

```
<ul>
<li>
    <div>
        <input type="radio">
    </div>
    <label>
        <img>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <div>
        <input type="radio">
    </div>
    <label>
        <img>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <div>
        <input type="radio">
    </div>
    <label>
        <img>
    </label>
</li>
<li>
    <div>
        <input type="radio">
    </div>
    <label>
        <img>
    </label>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

`li{ width : 100%; } 
li div{ width : 100%; float : left; } 
li label{ float : left }`

How about this?

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-bottom: .25em;
}
```

The 'margin-bottom' is to compensate for the fact that your div's *baseline* will be aligned with the middle of the image.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/rwfrQ/